# JSP EL and autoCompletion

Tags: java, jsp, intellij-idea, el

In my servlet:

```
request.setAttribute("list", myList);
```

In my Jsp:

```
<c:forEach var="item" items="${list}">
   ${item.name} and ${item.address}
</c:forEach>
```

How do I get autocompletion for `item.name` and `item.address` in IDE (IntelliJ)?

Can I use `<jsp:useBean>` for any other feature to make the type of 'item' explicit?

Comment: `item` could be anything. Did you try with usebean? Did you check what, if any, options are available for item quick fixes?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

For IntelliJ, you can use comment annotations, such as this:

```
<%--@elvariable id="list" type="java.util.List<your.item.class.Here>"--%>
```

To get this automatically, IntelliJ should be coloring `${items}` as a warning, since it wont have any idea what it is. Click on it and when the lightbulb pops up, click the option "Declare external variable in comment annotation." That will generate a comment annotation such as the one listed above.

Comment: This is awesome! In fact Alt + Enter (quick-fix) gives two options - declare external variable as (a) useBean, (b) comment annotation.

Comment: Yeah, I use comment annotations personally.