# Using model value as bean in JSP

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, intellij-idea, usebean

Given the following controller:

```
@Controller
public class LandingPageController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/landingPage", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String landingPage(Map<String, Object> model) {
        model.put("page", new LandingPage());
        return "landingPage";
    }
}
```

This would be my jsp:

```
<c:forEach items="${page.links}" var="link">
    <a href="${link.reference}">${link.label}</a>
</c:forEach>
```

IntelliJ shows the following warning:

> Cannot resolve variable 'page'

Using the quickfix, IntelliJ adds:

```
<jsp:useBean id="page" scope="request" type="com.myApp.LandingPage"/>
```

This in return leads to a duplicate variable exception on loading the site.

**Now my question:**

How can I define the variable in JSP (including its type) without creating a duplicate?**

Comment: What happens if you remove the useBean, ignore the IntelliJ warning, and deploy and run your app?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 
The page is shown correctly without any errors.

Comment: So you can delete your question.

Comment: It is about having the support from the code completion and typo avoidance on fields / methods of the bean. Not just about being able to show the site.

Comment: Then change your question. That's not at all what you're asking. But I'm afraid the answer is "there is no way: the JSP EL is a dynamic, reflection-based language"

Comment: Too bad there is no way. Thanks anyways for your clearification.

Answer (score 1):

```
<%--@elvariable id="page" type="com.myApp.LandingPage"--%>
<c:forEach items="${page.links}" var="link">
    <a href="${link.reference}">${link.label}</a>
</c:forEach>
```

Using the **@elvariable**, type information is now available and IntelliJ gives code completion as well as warnings if method (getLinks in this example) does not exist

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18038181/jsp-el-and-autocompletion)